# Does "Delete Local Content..." also delete mods and other third-party files?

Tags: steam

I'm about to uninstall and reinstall a Steam game. Unfortunately, while I have mods and other user files mixed within the game's own folder, the game files themselves take up a ton of space so I'd rather not have to back up all its contents before uninstalling.

Will the "Delete Local Content..." option delete everything in a game's folder, or will it preserve third-party files? If it doesn't preserve third-party files, it looks like I'll have to back them up manually.

In case it matters, the game I'm uninstalling is Team Fortress 2. Apparently, major updates have a bad habit of borking my game.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the game.

I've got no experience with TF2, but CS:Source — which uses same engine and should have similar directory layout. In case of CS:S, "Delete local content" did remove all mods.

Another game I've tried with were S.T.A.L.K.E.R series. All mods were also deleted in that case.

I'm guessing it really depends if mods are installed in same directory as game, or does game have separate directory for mods.

Comment: In short the answer is 'yes'. Following up from what vartec mentioned; All mods are saved to the same directory as the games folder. However if you have subscribed to a specific mod, then you will be able to download it again with ease when you next install that same game. [Click here to see more](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3084401)